# Pseudo element moves from below to above parent on CSS transform

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I have  button with a pseudo element I placed underneath to create a clicking effect. I wrote this code:

```css
button {
  appearance: none;
  --webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: #0070c9;
  border-radius: .3em;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
button::after {
  background-color: #005496;
  border-radius: .3em;
  bottom: -.2em;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
button:active, button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
button:active {
  transform: translateY(0.1em);
}
button:active::after {
  bottom: -.1em;
}
```

```html
<button>Button</button>
```

When the button is clicked, the pseudo element becomes the background of the button; I want the light background to remain over the pseudo element while the transform occurs and after. Is there a reason that the pseudo element moves under the text but above the background of the button?

Note: I am not using any vendor-prefixed CSS in my original code, I just added `--webkit-appearance: none;` to this page; I will use a post-processor to handle this later.

**Edit**

The button looks like the left when not in active state, and the the right image in active state.

[image: Unpressed button]
[image: Pressed button]

I do not want the button to become dark when it is in active state. I want the background to remain the same.

I want the button to look like this when it is clicked:

[image: What it should look like]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added a ::before pseudo element as well and then shifted the z-index of the :before and :after pseudo elements when the button is active. I have also added a span around the buttons text and added a positition of relative and a z-index of 3 to bring it to the front of the pseudo elements.

```css
button {
  appearance: none;
  background:none;
  --webkit-appearance: none;
  border-radius: .3em;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
button span {
   position:relative;
   z-index:3;
}
button::before, button::after {
  border-radius: .3em;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
button::before {
  background-color: #0070c9;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
button::after {
  background-color: #005496;
  bottom: -.2em;
  z-index: 1;
}
button:active, button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
button:active span {
  bottom: -.2em;
}
button:active::before {
  z-index:2;
  background:none;
}
button:active::after{
  z-index:1;
  background-color: #0070c9;
}
```

```html
<button><span>Button</span></button>
```